# Objective-c - 2 animations not working together

Tags: objective-c, core-animation

I'm trying to create an animation that when I click on a cell from a table view:

1) I create a clone of this cell and send it to the top of my view;
2) Send my tableview to the left

but I can't have them working together. With the code below, I have the animation of the cell going to the top but my tableview stays where it is (not moving to the left):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    //cloning UITableViewCell view for later work
    NSData *tempArchiveView = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]];
    UIView *headerView = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:tempArchiveView];

    headerView.frame = CGRectMake(0,
                                  headerView.frame.origin.y,
                                  headerView.frame.size.width,
                                  headerView.frame.size.height);
    //adding to the main view
    [self.view insertSubview:headerView aboveSubview:self.newsTableView];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        //move my tableview to the left
        self.newsTableView.center = CGPointMake(-300, tableView.center.y);

        //send my header to the top starting from 
        headerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, headerView.frame.size.width, headerView.frame.size.height);
    }];

}
```

I realize that when I remove this line:

```
[self.view insertSubview:headerView aboveSubview:self.newsTableView];
```

the table view goes to the left as I want, but I don't have the cell animation anymore

Regards!

Comment: your root problem is, you cannot use the `UITableViewCell` outside of a table view. you may need to deep-copy the cell's `contentView` only, and add to your view instead. have you tried that way yet?

Comment: I have just tried, still exactly the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    //clone tableview cell for later work
    NSData *tempArchiveView = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]];

    self.headerView = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:tempArchiveView];

    //save te frame in relation to tableview's supervir
    CGRect cellPositionOnWindow = [tableView rectForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    CGRect rectInSuperview = [tableView convertRect:cellPositionOnWindow toView:[tableView superview]];

    apply this frame to the clone
    self.headerView.frame = rectInSuperview;
    [self.view addSubview:self.headerView];


    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        //I decided to move the bounds instead of the frame
        self.view.bounds = CGRectMake(320, 
                                      self.view.frame.origin.y, 
                                      tableView.frame.size.width,
                                      tableView.frame.size.height);

        self.headerView.frame = CGRectMake(320,
                                           0,
                                           self.headerView.frame.size.width,
                                           self.headerView.frame.size.height);
    }];
}
```

It's working just fine, I could do the effect including another lateral view.